# Exponential equations e.g. $x^{x^2} = 8x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How does one go about solving an exponential equation with variable as base and in the exponent, such as:

$$x^{x^2} = 8x$$

I've seen people write (and am happy with):
$$x^{x^2-1} = 2^3$$

Followed by:
$$\Rightarrow x^2-1 = 3$$
$$\Rightarrow x = 2$$

This happens to be the right answer. But isn't the method wrong as the bases must be the same to justify this step?

Have I missed something? Is there another method to apply here?

Apologies for the straight forward question. I'm self-studying and you good people are the best for me to ask.

Comment: How do you go from $x^{x^2}=8x$ to $x^{2x-1}=2^3$ it should be $x^{x^2-1}=8$(assuming $x\neq 0$)

Comment: is $x=2$ one solution?

Comment: My mistake. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I think the following equation is much better. $x^{x^2}=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $$x \ne 0$$

$$x^{x^2} = 8x$$

$$\frac {x^{x^2}}{x} = 8$$

$$x^{x^2 - 1} = 8$$

$$x^{x^2 - 1} = 2^{2^2 - 1}$$

Now on comparing we get $$x = 2$$

Comment: But how will you prove that this is the only solution, or there exist some more (over the reals) ?

Comment: you will Need that $$x\ne 0$$

Comment: If you think there are more solutions. I also want to see.

Comment: Is it fine @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner?

Comment: $x \approx 0.121185$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Can you show me and others how you solved it

Comment: I didn't, W|A did it

Comment: Graphing the two functions shows two solutions. I also have no idea how to show the second non-integer solution.

Comment: See this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E%7Bx%5E2-1%7D+%3D8

Comment: Then may be there are other numbers also. But its not possible to find these values without using software.

Comment: No, $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ these are the only two solutions.

Comment: There are exactly two real solutions. You can see this by noting that the original equation is equivalent to $\log_8 x = \frac1{x^2-1}$ and seeing that the graphs of $y=\log_8 x$ and $y=\frac1{x^2-1}$ cross once in $(0,1)$ and once in $(1,\infty)$

Comment: Thanks for this answer Kanwaljit. So the piece I missed is realising you could write the exponent on RHS to be same as LHS. Is this something you always look for?

Comment: Yes sometimes it is possible to write.

Comment: How do you think computer found the other answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Taking logs, we write $f(x) = (x^2-1) \log(x)- \log(8)$. Our problem has the solutions $f(x)=0$ which occur at $x=2$ and $x \simeq 0.121185$. Taking $f''(x) = 2\log(x) - (x^2 - 1)/x^2 + 4$ one observes that  $f''(x) > 0$ for all positive $x$. So $f(x)$ is convex and there will be no other solutions $f(x)=0$.